# Mongodb Join on _id field from String to ObjectId. I already saw a similar post , but im trying literally the same and i cant get the solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two collections

1. Coach

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("584aac38686860d502929b8b"),
   "name" : "John"
}
```

2. Sessions

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("584aaca6686860d502929b8d"),
   "status" : true,
   "coach" : "584aac38686860d502929b8b"  
}
```

I want to join these collection based on the userId (in role collection) - _id ( in user collection).

i tried the below query:

```
Session.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { "coachId": { "$toString": "$_id" }}},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Coach.Collection.Name,  // also tried with "coach" here
    "localField": "coach",
    "foreignField": "coachId",
    "as": "output"
  }}
])
```

i am receiving an empty array.

i want to receive all sessions with my coach info.

I tried using $lookup $addFields and pipeline. But there's no way

Comment: You're going from Sessions to Coach, so your `localField` and `foreignField` are backwards. And `from` is the name of the collection so should just be `"Coach"` according to how you've described the situation.

Comment: i tried in that way , but still the same.

Comment: [mongo playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3oI2mJq1aip)